# How do I check object null checking inside setter method in java?

Tags: java

this is the usual way

```
productMenu = productMenuService.getProductMenuById(Integer.parseInt(request.getString("productMenuId")));
            if (productMenu != null) {
                productPost.setProductMenu(productMenu);
            }
```

can i do this not null object checking inside setter method

```
productPost.setProductMenu(productMenuService.getProductMenuById(Integer.parseInt(request.getString("productMenuId"))));
```

Trying to reduce the code. Would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: Why isn't the code inside the if-block just `productPost.setProductMenu(productMenu);`?

Comment: Consider that, I want to retrieve object and do null checking inside if block

Answer (score 2):

**Version >= Java 8**
You could use Optional to ensure only non null value will be set.

```
 Optional.ofNullable(request.getString("productMenuId"))
 .map(value-> Integer.parseInt(value))
 .map(productMenuService::getProductMenuById);
 .ifPresent(productPost::setProductName);
```

**Version < Java 8**

```
void setProductMenu(*ProductMenuType* productMenu) {
  // do all your checking before setting here
  if (productMenu != null) {
     productPost.setProductMenu(productMenu);
  }
}
```

But your case doesn't make sense(no else part) because if we are not setting a value for a variable, then by default it will be `NULL`

Comment: Personally, I prefer separating the single steps a la `Optional.ofNullable(request.getString("productMenuId")).map(Integer::parseInt).map(productMenuService::getProductMenuById).ifPresent(productPost::setProductMenu)`

Comment: @daniu and that's not only cleaner looking code (if you insert newline before each .map), but also more robust, since you're not risking getting exceptions being thrown by `Integer.parseInt` in case `request.getString("productMenuId")` was null

Comment: `Optional` should not be used as a replacement for `if`.

Comment: @VFR it dependent on the situation. For creating new object, Optional is good. It is not suited for updates. Here Optional is equal to given code.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(productMenuService.getProductMenuById(Integer.parseInt(request.getString("productMenuId")) == null){
   return new ResponseEntity<String>("Not found", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}else{
productMenu = productMenuService.getProductMenuById(Integer.parseInt(request.getString("productMenuId")));

}
//in your repository first check that data is present or not like this
repository.findById(id).isPresent(){
return repository.getOne(id);
}else return null
```

Answer (score -1):

Throw an exception.

If someone passes an invalid product menu ID to your application, *they made a mistake.*  You should not act like they did nothing wrong.  Your application certainly should not leave the old product menu in place and ignore the user’s request entirely.

```
if (productMenu == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid product menu ID.");
}

productPost.setProductMenu(productMenu);
```

While this won’t make your code shorter, it will make your code better.

A robust application does not pretend that it’s working when it is not in fact working.  To do otherwise would frustrate users and would make debugging a lot more difficult, as it could be weeks or months or years before the problem is discovered.

Ideally, you will want to create your own exception class, and throw that instead:

```
if (productMenu == null) {
    throw new InvalidProductMenuIDException("Invalid product menu ID.");
}

productPost.setProductMenu(productMenu);
```

where the exception class is simply:

```
public class InvalidProductMenuIDException
extends Exception {
    public InvalidProductMenuIDException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public InvalidProductMenuIDException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public InvalidProductMenuIDException(String message,
                                         Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you assume `null` as product id is invalid in OP's usecase

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Because a null product means the supplied product ID is invalid.  I have a hard time imagining a valid use case for allowing a browser or other client to supply a product ID that isn’t actually the ID of an existing product.